# What is the meaning of the asset risk contribution in a long-short portfolio?

Tags: risk, modern-portfolio-theory, longshort

If I have a portfolio of weights $\mathbf{x}$ and the covariance matrix of asset returns $\Sigma$ then the volatility contribution per asset is given as standard $\mathbf{x}' \Sigma$. For a standard long only portfolio with $\Sigma_i x_i=1$, if I want to increase the volatility of the portfolio, I would find the asset with the largest vol-contribution and increase its weight (or if I wanted to decrease my portfolio volatility I would decrease the weight of the asset with the largest vol-contribution).

However, for a long-short portfolio where some elements of $\mathbf{x}$ are negative and $\Sigma_i x_i=0$, we can get negative values for the volatility contribution $\mathbf{x}' \Sigma$. What does this mean if I want to increase (decrease) my portfolio volatility by adjusting the weights in $\mathbf{x}$?